# Copy Azure Files to Amazon-S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, powershell, amazon-s3, backup

I would like to copy a directory (with all its sub files, folders etc.) from azure file storage (**not azure blob storage**) to an aws s3 bucket on **powershell.**

So : Azure Files -> Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3

What I tried :

- using **Rclone** but rclone only takes into account blob and not file storage for the moment ([see here](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/365))
- use of **azcopy** but azcopy does not allow the following combination
  Azure Files (SAS) -> Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 (Access Key)

The process must not go through a local location (Virtual machine).

Any Ideas ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of an alternative that works.

The idea is

- To mount the azure file storage on disk. So it's not really "local"
  but rather a shared file. ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-CLBG8XR6XlMTyPRJIxjiew&epi=a1LgFw09t88-CLBG8XR6XlMTyPRJIxjiew&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__3sxdyfhkwwkfq33xkk0sohz3ze2xouoq2tgs3dff00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-CLBG8XR6XlMTyPRJIxjiew%29%28%29&irclickid=_3sxdyfhkwwkfq33xkk0sohz3ze2xouoq2tgs3dff00))
- I use Rclone to copy to S3 from the local path to the mounted
  disk.